# Can rationals be completed to reals?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

It's a well-known theorem that any metric space can be completed. Its proof essentially uses the completeness of the reals.
The rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ can be treated as an uncomplete metric space with the metrics $d:(x,y)\rightarrow |x-y|$.
The question arises: can the metric space $(\mathbb{Q},d)$  be completed without using the reals?
If I correctly remember it, I saw that construction in a course of mathematical analysis lectured at Moscow University
in 70s of the 20-th century. A proof and/or reference are welcome.

Comment: What construction of the reals do you know which uses the reals? That would be a circular definition, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos: There is no circular definition in my question. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I read your question as "Is there a way to define the reals without using reals" because the reals are often *defined* as the completion of the rationals. But of course, that's not a necessity, so your question is fine. I was just too quick with my interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, completions *don't* need the real numbers.

Look in Kelley's book for the chapter on uniform spaces, where it is hinted that they can be described by a set of axioms not so different from the axiom of a topology. You can find the system in Bourbaki, but it's not difficult to derive it. The axiom system is basically a description of *entourages*, special subsets of $X\times X$ containing the diagonal: an *entourage* for a metric space $(X,d)$ would be a subset of $X\times X$ containing a set of the form $\{(x,y):d(x,y)<r\}$, for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$. However, the axiom system never mentions the real numbers.

It is possible to define the concept of convergence and of Cauchy sequence only using *entourages* and to show that every uniform space has a completion using the set of Cauchy sequences modulo an equivalence relation, which set can be endowed with a uniform space structure and every Cauchy sequence in it converges.

Metric spaces are uniform spaces having a countable basis of *entourages* (basis in the sense of filter basis).

---

About getting the reals from the rational numbers, here's a construction similar to the one described above, which is a formalization of Cantor’s idea.

A *C-sequence* in the rational numbers is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that, for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $k$ with the property that, for every $m,n>k$, $|x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon$.

Real numbers are not used, as you see.

Now it's not difficult to show that the set $\mathscr{C}$ of C-sequence can be made into a ring, with pointwise addition and multiplication: the sum and product of C-sequences are C-sequences.

A *Z-sequence* in the rational numbers is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that, for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $k$ with the property that, for every $n>k$, $|x_n|<\varepsilon$.

It's easy to see that every Z-sequence is a C-sequence and that the set $\mathscr{Z}$ of Z-sequences is an ideal of $\mathscr{C}$.

Now the quotient ring $\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{C}/\mathscr{Z}$ can be shown to be complete in the sense that every C-sequence in it converges. And, guess what? It is a field that's isomorphic to the real numbers.

Basic steps.

1. $\mathscr{Z}$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathscr{C}$, so $\mathscr{R}$ is a field.
2. Define an order relation on $\mathscr{C}/\mathscr{Z}$ by declaring an element of the form $[(x_n)]=(x_n)+\mathscr{Z}$, where $(x_n)$ is a C-sequence, to be positive if there exist $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $k$ such that $\varepsilon>0$ and $x_n>\varepsilon$, for every $n>k$. Prove that $\mathscr{R}$ becomes an ordered field.
3. Embed $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathscr{R}$ in the unique possible way.
4. Define a C-sequence in $\mathscr{R}$ as at the beginning (only rational numbers).
5. Define a sequence $(x_n)$ to be convergent in $\mathscr{R}$ if there exists $x\in\mathscr{R}$ such that, for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $k$ with the property that, for all $n>k$, $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$.
6. Prove that all C-sequences converge in $\mathscr{R}$.

What's the idea in the last step? Take a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathscr{R}$. Each $x_n$ is the residue class of a sequence $(x_n^{(1)},x_n^{(2)},\dotsc)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that the sequence $y$ defined by $y_n=x_n^{(n)}$ is a C-sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ and that the given C-sequence converges to $[y]$.

Comment: Can you ground your "can be shown to be complete"? Can you give an accessible reference? TIA.

Comment: -1. Nice, but empty words. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03467.pdf) is a reference. I'd like to quote "As noted, the construction lacks in rigor".

Comment: @user64494 I added the steps to be done.

Comment: @user64494 Weierstrass possibly lacked in rigor. Not what I presented. Please, be more careful in commenting.

Comment: @edreg: Sorry, I still see an idea, not a proof.

Comment: @edreg: -1 is cancelled.

Comment: @user64494 This is not the place to give full proofs that are a few pages long when spelled out completely. However, I added a reference to uniform spaces. Look for them.

Comment: @edreg: Don't find it useful. Still no reference or proof. Concerning upvotes. see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awards_and_decorations_received_by_Leonid_Brezhnev).

Comment: @user64494 Aren't *look for uniform spaces*, Kelley and Bourbaki references? Anyway, the [description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) is quite useful.

Comment: @edreg:  Can you explain step 6, especially ''Show that the sequence $y$ defined by $y_n=x^{(n)}_n$ is a $C$-sequence in Q and that the given $C$-sequence converges to $[y]$", in details? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Each element of $\mathscr{R}$ is represented by a sequence; if you have a sequence in $\mathscr{R}$, take the first item in the sequence representing the first item, the second item in the sequence representing the second item and so on. You get a sequence in the rational numbers and your task is to prove convergence.

Comment: @edreg: I understand the notations. I don't see any proof of that key point. The step 6 is not obvious and trivial.

Comment: @user64494 It's certainly not obvious.

Comment: @edreg: Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such style.

Comment: @user64494 I'm not sure why you're expecting a full, detailed proof and calling this answer "empty words" and saying that you "don't find it useful". Giving the rough idea behind a certain concept without fully spelling out the proof is often just as useful as the full proof, if not more so.

Comment: @YiFan: I call things by their proper names. A key point is not explained.

Comment: @user64494 I'm not interested in arguing with you, but I think you're the one being ungrateful and unreasonable here, to someone who has written for you an excellent answer. If this is always your attitude, I'm not sure why anyone should help you. This is my last word on the subject.